# TSQL string regex matching

Tags: sql, regex, string, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to check if a string variable matches a regex in SQL Server? I want something simple like `@stringVariable = @regex` and get as result something like true/false.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean Microsoft SQL Sever, then you can't as it doesn't support regex out of the box.

However you could shell out the process to a CLR Stored procedure, or if it is a very simple regex, you might be able to use a `LIKE` keyword.

[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) is a link about CLR regex support. I used this myself a few years ago until I abandoned the idea of using regex in my case!